# jquery validations are not working when i click on submit button

Tags: php, jquery, html, validation

I have written a html form and jquery to perform the validations. But when i click the submit button, nothing is happening. I can't understand what is going on, whether the form is linking up with the jquery file or not. Please any check my code and help me.

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>validation</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="reg_form">
<p>Name:</p>
<p><input id="name" name="name" type="text"></p>
<p>What's your name?</p>

<p>Email:</p>
<p><input id="email" name="email" type="text"></p>
<p>Enter mail id</p>

<p>Password:</p>
<p><input id="pass1" name="pass1" type="password"></p>
<p>More than 8 characters</p>

<p>Password:</p>
<p><input id="pass2" name="pass2" type="password"></p>
<p>same as above</p>

<p>phone</p>
<p><input id="phone" name="phone" type="text"></p>
<p>What's your number?</p>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var form = $("#reg_form");
 var name = $("#name");
 var nameDetails = $("#nameDetails");
 var email = $("#email");
 var emailDetails = $("#emailDetails");
 var pass1 = $("#pass1");
 var pass2 = $("#pass2");
 var pass1Details = $("#pass1Details");
 var pass2Details = $("#pass2Details");
 var phone = $("#phone");
 var phoneDetails = $("#phoneDetails");
 var button = $("#submit");

 name.blur(validateName);
 email.blur(validateEmail);
 pass1.blur(validatePass1);
 pass2.blur(validatePass2);
 phone.blur(validatePhone);

 name.keyup(validateName);
 email.keyup(validateEmail);
 pass1.keyup(validatePass1);
 pass2.keyup(validatePass2);
 phone.keyup(validatePhone);

 form.submit(function(){
  if(validateName() & validateEmail & validatePass1 & validatePass2() &     validatePhone()){
  return true;
  }else{
  return false;
  }
 });

 function validateName(){
 if(name.val().length<5){
 name.addClass("error");
 nameDetails.text("Your name should have atleast 5 characters");
 nameInfo.addClass("error");
 return false;
 }else{
 name.removeClass("error");
 nameDetails.text("Whats your name?");
 }
 }

 function validateEmail(){
 var a = $("#email").val();
 var regexp = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+[a-za-zA-Z0-9_-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+.[a-z]{2,4}$/;

 if(filter.text(a)){
 email.removeClass("error");
 emailDetails.text("Enter mail id");
 emailDetails.removeClass("error");
 return true;
 }else{
 email.addClass("error");
 emailDetails.text("Enter valid mail id");
 emailDetails.addClass("error");
 }
 }
 function validatePass1(){
 if(pass1.val().length<8){
 pass1.addClass("error");
 pass1Details.text("8 characters or more");
 pass1Details.addClass("error");
 return false;
 }else{
 pass1.removeClass("error");
 pass1.Details.text("Enter mail id");
 pass1.Details.removeClass("error");
 return true;
 } 
}

 function validatePass2(){

 if(pass2.val().length < 1){
 pass2.addClass("error");
 pass2Details.text("8 characters or more");
 pass2Details.addClass("error");
 return false;
 }

 if(pass1.val()!== pass2.val()){
 pass2.addClass("error");
 pass2Details.text("8 characters or more");
 pass2Details.addClass("error");
 return false;
 }else{
 pass2.removeClass("error");
 pass2.Details.text("Same as above");
 pass2.Details.removeClass("error");
 return true;
 } 
}

function validatePhone(){
var b = $("#phone").val();
var regexp = /[0-9]{10}/;

if(filter.text(b)){
 email.removeClass("error");
 emailDetails.text("Enter phone number");
 emailDetails.removeClass("error");
 return true;
 }else{
 email.addClass("error");
 emailDetails.text("Enter valid phone number");
 emailDetails.addClass("error");
 }
}

});
```

Comment: I'd look in your devtool console, I'd expect you to see a few errors to point you in the right direction

Comment: `validateEmail & validatePass1` don't you think this requires `()`.

Comment: ok. I corrected that. Bt still it isn't working

Comment: Run you page in chrome and debug in chrome console, check if the break points are hit or if console shows any errors. To open the developer tool just hit F12, go to source tab and select the js file to debug.

Comment: Also try putting alerts to check if the validation methods are called, I can also see some validation method do not return true.

Comment: You are trying to give error messages in #nameDetails,#emailDetails, etc. But i dont see elements with those ids in the html part. am i missing something here or did you ?

Comment: @GirishSakhare: I have checked in the console. There are no errors showing up and also there are no breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

use the statements like this,

```
var name = $("#name ").val();
```

Or

```
var name = jQuery("#name ").val();
```

and then try...it will work...

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var form = $("#reg_form").val();
  var name = $("#name").val();
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this..**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var name = $("#name").val();
 var nameDetails = $("#nameDetails").val();
 var email = $("#email").val();
 var emailDetails = $("#emailDetails").val();
 var pass1 = $("#pass1").val();
 var pass2 = $("#pass2").val();
 var pass1Details = $("#pass1Details").val();
 var pass2Details = $("#pass2Details").val();
 var phone = $("#phone").val();
 var phoneDetails = $("#phoneDetails").val();
});
```